# Tabs with <script> removeClass & addClass

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to add  videos inside tabs here is an example

```
<script data-config="//config.playwire.com/17003/videos/v2/3745040/zeus.json" data-css="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/skins/default.css" data-height="480" data-width="853" src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My problem is everytime I change tab it doesn't show the video

With iframes videos is working

Here is what I've tried so far:

jQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#sidebar").tabs({
        event: "click",
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(ui);
            var _tab = ui.newTab;
            $('#sidebar li').removeClass('active');
            $(_tab).addClass('active');
        },
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Video1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Video2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Video3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<script data-config="//config.playwire.com/17003/videos/v2/3714373/zeus.json" data-css="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/skins/default.css" data-height="390" data-width="630" src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<script data-config="//config.playwire.com/17003/videos/v2/3745793/zeus.json" data-css="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/skins/default.css" data-height="390" data-width="630" src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<script data-config="//config.playwire.com/17003/videos/v2/3745040/zeus.json" data-css="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/skins/default.css" data-height="390" data-width="630" src="//cdn.playwire.com/bolt/js/zeus/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UnYx9/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your other videos don't have a height.

Try this:

```
#tabs-2 div, #tabs-3 div {
     height: 390px !important;
}
```